# How would I apply Wick's theorem to the time-ordered product of three fields?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

I think I know how to apply Wick's theorem in order to expand the time-ordered product of quantum fields, but I just want to verify my understanding. Could someone perform it for the arbitrary product:

$$\mathcal{T}[\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_3)]$$

Thank you for any clarification that you might provide.

Comment: you'll get a better response if you give an equation (left-hand-side equals right-hand-side), rather than just an orphaned expression.

Comment: it's done on page 181 of Itzykson-Zuber 1980 edition.

Answer (score 2):

The case of three fields is given as:
\begin{equation} T\{\phi_1 \phi_2 \phi_3\}=N\{\phi_1 \phi_2 \phi_3\}+C\{\phi_1 \phi_2\}\phi_3 + C\{\phi_2 \phi_3\}\phi_1 + C\{\phi_1 \phi_3\}\phi_2\end{equation}
where $C$ denotes the contraction of the fields inside its brackets. Hope that it helps.